# plot some points as a trajectory of tracking from video / c++

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing

I have a vector of pair-value which contains the coordinates of some points.

```
Coordinates.push_back(std::make_pair(row,col));
```

I want to plot them with different colors in real-time.

this "cvPoint function"value in Opencv does not accept any vector as an input for plotting.

should I find another library to achieve that?

I am newbie and Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV for this purpose with the function [polylines.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html) This function plots a line following a set of points (cv::Points) stored in a vector. Here an example:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> trajectoryPoints; /* Vector with coordinates */

(...) /* Here you fill your vector */

const cv::Point *pts = (const cv::Point*) Mat(trajectoryPoints).data;
int npts = Mat(trajectoryPoints).rows;

polylines(yourImage, &pts,&npts, 1, false, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 10, CV_AA, 0);
```

This code draws in "yourImage" the trajectory defined as a set of points in the array. Please, have a look at [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#polylines) for the understanding of the parameters.